# Question about dean edwards packer

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery I use to save all my selectors in a variable. Then the browser only have to do doom travel once wich speeds up the site a bit...

I am also using Dean Edwards packer for my scripts.

**My question is: Is this realy needed or will Dean Edwards packer do this for me?
I mean will Dean Edwards packer save the selectors in to variables for me...**

Will this:

```
$('#my_div').click(function() {

//stuff

});
```

Be like this after Dean Edwards packer:

```
var $my_div = $('#my_div');

$my_div.click(function() {

//stuff

});
```

Comment: why not run a sample case though the packer and see if it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not. (Tested at [here](http://jscompress.com/))

Original Source Code :

```
$('#my_div').click(function(){ alert('hai'); });
```

Packed :

`eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('$(\'#0\').1(2(){3(\'4\')});',5,5,'my_div|click|function|alert|hai'.split('|'),0,{}))`

In eval() (used document.write() to see result) :

```
$('#my_div').click(function(){alert('hai')});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will continue to cache my javascript manually :)